# Get dates from array and disable those dates from calendar that repeat more than twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I want to get dates from array which are repeated 3 times so I can disable those dates from calendar.

```js
function disbaleDate() {
  const arr = [
    "1/6/2022",
    "12/6/2022",
    "4/6/2022",
    "6/6/2022",
    "1/6/2022",
    "1/6/2022",
  ];
  const increment = [];


    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (arr[j] === arr[i]) {
          increment.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  
  console.log(increment);
}

disbaleDate();
```

Comment: so u want to get the repeated date from given  array what I understand

Comment: `backendData` is undefined here; we see no "calendar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, updating my answer

```js
// reducer willproduce an object with the date as the key, and the amount repeated as the value
const countRepeated = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a[c]) {
        a[c] = a[c] + 1;
        return a;
    }
    
    a[c] = 1;
    return a;
}, {})

// will filter those whose values are greater than 2
return Object.keys(countRepeated).filter( date => date > 2)
```

Comment: bruh i want to get those dates which are repeated more than twice

Comment: this wasn't in the original question, for that instance, try using a reducer for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function disableDate() {
    const arr = ["1/6/2022", "12/6/2022", "4/6/2022", "6/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/6/2022",];
       
    const backendData = ["12/12/2022", "12/6/2021", "14/6/2022", "16/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "11/6/2022",];
        
    const increment = [];

    if (backendData.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < backendData.length; i++) {
            if (arr.includes(backendData[i])) {
                increment.push(backendData[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(increment);
}
disableDate();
```

Comment: bruh i want to get those dates which are repeated 3 times then i want to add that in an array, im creating a app where everyone can post ads and after three same dates from different user no one can post that add cause date is going to be disabled

Answer (score 0):

```js
const disable  = () => {

const arr = [
      "1/6/2022",
      "12/6/2022",
      "4/6/2022",
      "6/6/2022",
      "1/6/2022",
      "1/6/2022",
    ];
    let data =[];
    data = arr.filter((el, i) => i !== arr.indexOf(el) )
    let result = data.filter((el,i) => i ===data.indexOf(el))
    
   
    
 return  result;
    
}

console.log(disable())
```

Comment: it is working for any date which is repeated twice, i only need those dates which comes thrice, please help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you solve it or need help as of now and could u tell me again your problem statement, if date is repeated more than 2 day then only we have to show the results